# Are tax-free investments still tax free when taking distributions?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, ira

If you read the 'Power of Zero', he talks about putting tax free investments into your traditional IRA.  That way, you won't incur any taxes when you take distributions.

Maybe I misunderstood what he was referring to.  In practice, it does not work that way.  Anything you take out of your IRA will be taxed.

Can someone verify what the author was talking about in this regard?

Comment: @Joe Many IRA custodians will not let the account holder invest in municipal bonds or other investments that yield taxfree income. Besides, _anything_ coming out a traditional IRA is treated as _cash_ for the purposes of income tax. Even if a custodian allows the investor to take an in-kind distribution of, say. stocks held within the IRA, the distribution is deemed to be of cash in the amount of the value of the stocks on the date of the distribution, and _none_ of that amount can be treated as, for example, capital gains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> putting tax free investments into your traditional IRA

I'm not religious, but I know there's a special place in hell for anyone advising this.

Your Roth is tax free regardless of what was held inside.

Your traditional IRA if funded with pre-tax money, is 100% taxed on withdrawals regardless of what was invested in the account.

I'll give the author the benefit of the doubt and assume you misunderstood. I see Ed Slott wrote the introduction to that book, and Mr Slott knows his stuff. If not, the author got it very wrong.

Comment: +1 for your comment, and almost a -1 for the last sentence but one. All the Ed Slott programs that I have seen (on public TV, yet!) seem to be telling folks to sell all their investments and buy life-insurance policies instead.

Comment: I mean the Ed Slott that's written books and article for Financial Planning magazine. I don't recognize the guy on PBS fundraiser shows. (same guy, I know)

Comment: I am not sure what "same guy I know)" means. Are there two different people, the book writer and the TV guy? Reviews of the book "Power of Zero" (the book the OP is asking about) on Amazon suggest that it is entirely based on what seems to be just a chapter in one of Ed Slott(the book writer)' books, and what I have seen of Ed Slott the TV guy seems to be mostly that same chapter dramatized for the benefit of a studio audience that is lapping it up.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that his writing is great, he has credibility. Yet, somehow his TV persona is like a different person. Similar to Jim Cramer. Crazy on TV, yet pretty good advice in his books.

Answer (score 2):

Zeros are, after all, bonds, so even though they don't make any actual interest payments, you pay taxes on "imputed interest" each year if you hold them in taxable accounts, as if they had paid interest and you had reinvested it. In a non-taxable account you don't do that.

EDIT: as @DilipSarwate pointed out, in a non-taxable account the gains on zeros, like all other gains, is taxed at distribution. He also more correctly referred to it as a tax-**deferred** account. You can't hide from taxes.

Comment: But when the OP takes a _distribution_ from a tax-deferred account, that interest will get taxed then.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - yes.